# Need Help in DFD Diagram for online hotel booking system

Tags: database-design

[image]

Hi friends,
          I am creating a data flow diagram for online hostel booking system. not sure if i created a correct diagram or not any help would be appreciated.

thanks in advance

Comment: Yes It look correct. What is your problem?

Comment: Data Flow Diagrams are well suited to documenting systems where data is stored in files or systems where there is some ETL involved.  In a transactional system built on a relational database, your data doesn't "flow" anywhere.  The only information in your DFD is actors and actions.  What you want is probably more something like a Use Case Diagram, not a Data Flow Diagram.

Comment: Hi brown, i read one book called Systems Analysis & Design In A Changing World (5th Ed.) and i came up with good dfd if you could go through please http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/76162/context-diagram-and-data-flow-diagram-for-online-booking-system